# Is it accurate to say that in getting the time efficiency of an algorithm, computer specification and running applications are not affecting its data?

Tags: algorithm, performance, processing-efficiency

I am creating a board game that uses Negamax and Alpha-Beta Prunning to test its time and space efficiency. My question is, is there a proof that in gathering data of the time the Computer specifications and running programs will not affect the time results?

Comment: What do you mean by "time results"? Can you be more specific about what you're worried will happen during testing?

Comment: Your question about a proof is beside the point. You want to know which algorithm you should use. Try one and tune the daylights out of it by [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). Then try the other method and tune it as far as you can. Then stopwatch each one to see which takes less time. You can't tell which one is better if you haven't tuned them as far as possible, because the better one might be artificially slowed down by something you could easily fix, like too many `new`s.

Comment: What i meant is that we are trying to compare the two algorithms and gather the time and space efficiency. The time efficiency is a calculated  time to finish the node search. Is computer specification affect the result of   the time in searching the node?

Comment: `Is computer specification affect the result of the time` - of course it will.  A faster computer will be able to compute the result faster.